# How can i run Huwei E173 data card on 10.04?

Tags: mobile-broadband

Please tell me How can i run Huwei E173 data card in Ubuntu 10.4. When i connect data card there is nothing happening related to network recognizing process please help

Answer (score 1):

## Install Huwaei Mobile Partner!

[Here](https://rapidshare.com/#!download%7C17p7%7C3347557351%7CMobile.Partner.Linux.21.003.28.00.03.zip%7C15662%7C0%7C0) is an externel download link for **Huawei Mobile Partner 21**.(Sometimes it already comes inside your dongal) Download and install it at your own risk. Perform a reboot after the installation and, network manager  will identify your device within 3 minutes.

## Installation

There should be script file called **"install.sh"** or a similar one inside the **Huawei Mobile Partner** package. View the **Properties** of that file, and navigate to the **Permissions** tab. Tick the check box, **Execute**, and enter the below command in Terminal to begin the installation:

> sudo **install.sh**

You have to give the path of the **install.sh** instead of just typing **Install.sh**

After installing the driver you will be able to connect to the internet. If not, try a different version Huawei Mobile Partner.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow instructions Here , On [Huawei Modem](http://biggenius.org/modem-manager-gui-for-ubuntu/)